# When can products of linear terms differ by a constant?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, examples-counterexamples, diophantine-equations

We have

$$ X(X+3) + 2 = (X+1)(X+2)$$

and

$$ X(X+4)(X+5) + 12 = (X+1)(X+2)(X+6)$$

and

$$ X(X+4)(X+7)(X+11) + 180 = (X+1)(X+2)(X+9)(X+10).$$

Do similar polynomial identities exist for each degree?

That is, for which positive integers $n$ do there exist integers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ and $b_1, \ldots, b_n$ such that

$$\prod_{i=1}^n (X + a_i) + c = \prod_{i=1}^n (X+b_i)$$

for some nonzero integer $c$?

Specific examples for the cases $n \ge 5$ are also helpful.

An answer to this question might shed light on [this unsolved question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/492326/). [This other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1076358/) asks for all such identities where $n=3$.

Comment: Hi Benjamin Wright, would you be helped by a proof for non integers $a_k$, $b_k$ and $c$?

Comment: @NancyBoy The question is rather trivial if you allow $a_k,b_k\in\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: That what I was thinking Servaes

Comment: @NancyBoy No, I'm aware that it follows from the fundamental theorem of algebra if you allow complex $a_k$ and $b_k$

Comment: It feels a bit similar to Vinogradov's mean-value theorem, here with $s=n$ and $k=n-1$ resp. $k=n$ but obviously the main conjecture doesn't help you here. You'd want to show that with $k=n$ there are quantifiably less solutions to the system. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinogradov%27s_mean-value_theorem

Comment: See a similar problem around the bottom of page 3 here (open access) https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2012/175-3/p12 If you keep digging maybe you'll find a conjecture that implies the answer to the question is yes.

Comment: @BartMichels Just want to point out that the question is equivalent to finding two random variables $X, Y$ each uniformly distributed on $n$ integer points that have equal moments of order up to $n-1$.

Comment: Reminds a bit about the observation (also due to Prouhet) locally described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/163369/11619). The construction there yields a sequence of pairs of polynomials with  a prescribed number of equal highest degree terms. Not surprisingly, the degrees of those polynomials blow up on your face (the degrees are $2^m$ when we are guaranteed $m$ non-trivial equal leading coefficients).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: there are solutions for $n \leq 10$ and for $n=12$. Otherwise it's a well known open problem. See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prouhet%E2%80%93Tarry%E2%80%93Escott_problem) and here: http://euler.free.fr/eslp/TarryPrb.htm ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20231102082658/http://euler.free.fr/eslp/TarryPrb.htm)).

The question is equivalent to the following:

> Given $n$, do there exist integers $a_1, \ldots, a_n, b_1, \ldots, b_n$ such that
> $$\forall j < n: a_1^j + \cdots + a_n^j = b_1^j + \cdots + b_n^j$$
> but
> $$a_1^n + \cdots + a_n^n \neq b_1^n + \cdots + b_n^n \, ?$$

(For each $j < n$ the polynomial $X_1^j + \cdots + X_n^j$ is a polynomial in the elementary symmetric polynomials of degree $\leq j$ where the one of degree $j$ occurs isolated and with only a linear term. This follows from the [fundamental theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials).)

In this form the question apppears in the literature surrounding [Vinogradov's Mean Value Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinogradov%27s_mean-value_theorem), for example here starting on the bottom of page 3 ("Tarry’s problem"):

> Wooley, T., *Vinogradov’s mean value theorem via efficient congruencing*, https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2012/175-3/p12.

In the notations there, the question is whether $W(n-1, 2) = n$. (It is clear that $W(n-1, 2)$ cannot possibly be smaller because polynomials can only have so many roots.) Below Theorem 1.13 it says the answer is positive for $n \leq 10$ and for $n=12$ (there is a typo that makes you think it is for $n \leq 11$ and for $n=13$) and it refers to this page which lists solutions to a slightly more general problem: http://euler.free.fr/eslp/eslp.htm ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20231103045525/http://euler.free.fr/eslp/eslp.htm)).

For example for $n = 7$ look at the examples under the header "k=1,2,3,4,5,6".

I don't know when that page was last updated. You can search for recent literature on Tarry's problem or the "Tarry-Escott problem of degree $n-1$". As far as I have found, the degree 10 ($n=11$) case is still open.

Comment: +1 Great answer. As for your last paragraph; the website itself claims to have been last updated on May 6th, 2001. This article: [https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2304.11254](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.11254.pdf) is quite recent, and gives a nice overview of the history of the problem and the progress that has been made so far. It does not mention any solutions for $n=11$ or $n>12$.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the respective $a_i$ and $b_i$ values are distinct, the values for $c$ you provide for degrees 2, 3, and 4 are minimal. The minimal values of $c$ for degrees $5$ and $6$ are given by the following equalities.

$$x(x + 4)(x + 8)(x + 16)(x + 17) + 5040 = (x + 1)(x + 2)(x + 10)(x + 14)(x + 18),$$

$$x(x + 5)(x + 6)(x + 16)(x + 17)(x + 22) + 100800 = (x + 1)(x + 2)(x + 10)(x + 12)(x + 20)(x + 21).$$

I have been unable to find a degree $7$ solution. This is not for lack of searching. Unless there is a bug in my program, $c$ must be larger than $60,000,000$ in the minimal degree $7$ solution (if it exists).

I have also attempted to search selective larger values of $c$ (multiples of $100800$, highly composite numbers, b-smooth numbers for small b, etc.) for a solution with degree $7$, to no avail.

If we allow for duplicate $b_i$ values, it is possible to find smaller acceptable $c$ values but only for even degrees.

$$x(x + 2) + 1 = (x + 1)^2,$$

$$x(x + 3)(x + 4)(x + 7) + 36 = (x + 1)^2(x + 6)^2,$$

$$x(x + 3)(x + 5)(x + 11)(x + 13)(x + 16) + 14400 = (x + 1)^2(x + 8)^2(x + 15)^2.$$

I do not know what could be obstructing a solution for degrees $\geq 7$.

Comment: Possibly worth noting: the sequence $\sigma_n=\{2, 12, 180, 5040, 100800\}$ doesn't appear in OEIS anywhere. The sequence $\{1, 2, 4, 8, 36\}=(2n)!/\sigma_n$ does occur, but none of the occurences have a plausible match to this; it also seems like $12!/\sigma_6$ (if it exists) will have to be much smaller than 36 based on the bounds of your testing.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_5,c\in\Bbb{Z}$ with $c\neq0$ be such that
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(X-a_i)-\prod_{i=1}^n(X-b_i)=c.\tag{1}$$
Without loss of generality we may order the coefficients such that $a_i\leq a_j$ and $b_i\leq b_j$ whenever $i\leq j$, and interchange the $a_i$ and $b_i$ such that $a_1\leq b_1$. Moreover, for all $t\in\Bbb{Z}$ we have
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(X+t-a_i)-\prod_{i=1}^n(X+t-b_i)=c,$$
in particular for $t:=a_1$, and so without loss of generality the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are all nonnegative.

---

**Some observations:** Plugging in $0$ or $a_k$ or $b_k$, for all $k$ we have
$$c=\prod_{i=1}^n(b_k-a_i)=-\prod_{i=1}^n(a_k-b_i)=(-1)^n\left(\prod_{i=1}^na_i-\prod_{i=1}^nb_i\right).$$
In particular, we see that $a_i\neq b_j$ for all $i$ and $j$ because $c$ is nonzero. As a consequence, for $k=1$ we see that all factors in the second product are negative, and so $c$ is positive if and only if $n$ is odd. Moreover, we see that if $n$ is odd (even), then the number of negative factors in the second product is odd (even), regardless of $k$, and the number of negative factors in the first product is even (odd), regardless of $k$.

**Proposition 1:** For all $k$, the number of $i$ with $a_k<b_i<a_{k+1}$ is even, and the number of $i$ with $b_k<a_i<b_{k+1}$ is even.

*Proof.* We prove the claim for $a_k<b_i<a_{k+1}$; the other half of the claim is entirely analogous. If $a_k=a_{k+1}$ then the claim is trivial, so suppose $a_k<a_{k+1}$. Because $c$ is nonzero, the number of negative factors in the products
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(a_k-b_i)=-c=\prod_{i=1}^n(a_{k+1}-b_i),$$
is congruent mod $2$. This proves the claim.

**Proposition 2:** For all $i$ we have $a_i<b_i$ if $i$ is odd, and $a_i>b_i$ if $i$ is even.

*Proof.* The integral polynomial
$f=\prod_{i=1}^n(X-a_i)$
has precisely $n$ roots, counted with multiplicity, and hence it has precisely one extremum between each pair of distinct consecutive roots. This means that whenever $a_i\neq a_{i+1}$, the interval $[a_i,a_{i+1}]$ contains at most two solutions to $f(x)=c$. Of course we have
$$f(b_k)=\prod_{i=1}^n(b_k-a_i)=c+\prod_{i=1}^n(b_k-b_i)=c,$$
and so we see that each interval $[a_i,a_{i+1}]$ contains at most two of the coefficients $b_k$. By symmetry each interval $[b_i,b_{i+1}]$ contains at most two of the coefficients $a_k$. By proposition $1$ every such interval contains an even number of these coefficients, from which it follows that the $a_i$ and $b_i$ alternate in pairs.

Next, to see that $a_1\neq a_2$, note that by the Gauss-Lucas theorem, all zeros of the derivative of
$$g=\prod_{i=1}^n(X-b_i),$$
are contained in the interval $[b_1,b_n]$. This means there is at most one solution to $g(x)=-c$ with $x<b_1$, which must then be $a_1$. If $a_2=a_1$ then $g(x)+c$ has a double zero at $a_1$, meaning that $g'(a_1)=0$, contradicting the Gauss-Lucas theorem.

This means that the $a_i$ and $b_i$ must be ordered as
$$a_1<b_1\leq b_2<a_2\leq a_3<b_3\leq b_4<a_4\leq\ldots,$$
which proves the proposition.

---

I will not continue this line of investigation, as I have just seen the answer by Bart Michels pointing out that this problem is equivalent to the Prouhet-Tarry-Escott Problem, which has been open for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I've been awake for over 50 hours, this is my attempt at catching sleep.

Here's a rather convoluted argument that such coefficients exist for every positive integer $n$: Given $n$, for each positive integer $k$ let $e_k$ denote the $k$-th elementary symmetric polynomial, so that
$$e_1=\sum_nX_i,\qquad e_2=\sum_nX_iX_j\qquad\ldots\qquad e_n=\prod_n X_i.$$

---

**Theorem:** (Fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials)
For a commutative unital ring $A$, for every symmetric polynomial $P\in A[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ there exists a unique polynomial $Q\in A[Y_1,\ldots,Y_n]$ such that
$$P(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=Q(e_1(X_1,\ldots,X_n),\ldots,e_n(X_1,\ldots,X_n)).$$
Equivalently, for a commutative unital ring $A$, let $X:=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be indeterminates and let $e(X):=(e_1(X),\ldots,e_n(X))$. Then the set of symmetric polynomials in $A[X]$ is precisely the subring $A[e(X)]\subset A[X]$, or more explicitly the subring
$$A[e_1(X_1,\ldots,X_n),\ldots,e_n(X_1,\ldots,X_n)]\subset A[X_1,\ldots,X_n],$$
and moreover the $e_k(X)$ are algebraically independent over $A$.

---

Now you want to find $a,b\in\Bbb{Z}^n$ such that $e_k(a)=e_k(b)$ for all $k<n$, but $e_n(a)\neq e_n(b)$. Suppose such $a$ and $b$ do not exist. Then with $A:=(A_1,\ldots,A_n)$ and $B:=(B_1,\ldots,B_n)$ indeterminates, and $e(X):=(e_1(X),\ldots,e_n(X))$, the polynomial
$$e_n(A)-e_n(B)\in\Bbb{Z}[e(A),e(B)],$$
vanishes on the zero locus of the ideal
$$I:=\Big\langle e_k(A)-e_k(B):\ k<n\Big\rangle\subset\Bbb{Z}[e(A),e(B)],$$
and so by the Nullstellensatz $(e_n(A)-e_n(B))^r\in I$ for some positive integer $r$. Of course $I$ is radical because it is the kernel of the ring homomorphism
$$\Bbb{Z}[e(A),e(B)]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}[e(A)]:\ e(B)\ \longmapsto\ e(A),$$
and so $r=1$. That is to say there are $c_k(A,B)\in\Bbb{Z}[e(A),e(B)]$ such that
$$e_n(A)-e_n(B)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}c_k(A,B)(e_k(A)-e_k(B)).$$
But then evaluating at $B=0$ yields a contradiction with the fact that the $e_k(A)$ are algebraically independent. Hence such $a$ and $b$ must exist.

Comment: This is a little outside my comfort zone, but I think that the Nullstellensatz does not apply, since we're considering the zero locus of an ideal defined over the integers rather than an algebraically closed field.

Comment: The example that I'm thinking of is that $A_1 + B_1$ vanishes over the zero locus of $I = \langle A_1^2 + B_1^2 \rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}[A_1, B_1]$, but there is no positive $r$ such that $(A_1+B_1)^r \in I$.

Comment: @BenjaminWright I agree entirely, and will think about a fix. The current form of the argument is unnecessarily roundabout anyway.